# Redgate SQL Prompt equivalent for PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, autocomplete, add-on, red-gate-sql-prompt

I'm starting at a new company after coming from a previous role where I could rely on Redgate's SQL Prompt with a MySQL environment. I'm now working with a Postgresql environment (SQL Workbench/J) and was wondering if anyone had come across any similar programs for Postgresql to make the query writing a bit less tedious and time intensive.

I'm aware of the CNTRL + Space option for suggesting columns/tables, hoping for something that automatically prompts.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean you used SQL Prompt with MSSQL (SQL Server), or really with MySQL? I can't find any info on using SQL Prompt with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full-featured GUI tool for PostgreSQL is [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/).

Among many other useful features, it has a [query tool](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.x/query_tool.html) with code completion and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dbForge Studio for PostgreSQL software to meet your needs, and this will help you to use this software in accordance with what is in the SQL Prompt program.
I hope the explanation I gave was useful to you.